# Find items with belongs_to associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, find, associations

I have a model called Kase each "Case" is assigned to a contact person via the following code:

```
class Kase < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :jobno
  has_many :notes, :order => "created_at DESC"

  belongs_to :company # foreign key: company_id
  belongs_to :person # foreign key in join table
  belongs_to :surveyor,
             :class_name => "Company",
             :foreign_key => "appointedsurveyor_id"
  belongs_to :surveyorperson,
             :class_name => "Person",
             :foreign_key => "surveyorperson_id"
```

I was wondering if it is possible to list on the contacts page all of the kases that that person is associated with.

I assume I need to use the find command within the Person model? Maybe something like the following?

```
def index
@kases = Person.Kase.find(:person_id)
```

or am I completely misunderstanding everything again?

Thanks,

Danny

EDIT:

If I use:

```
@kases= @person.kases
```

I can successfully do the following:

```
<% if @person.kases.empty? %>
  No Cases Found
<% end %>

<% if @person.kases %>
 This person has a case assigned to them
<% end %>
```

but how do I output the "jobref" field from the kase table for each record found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe following will work:

```
@person.kase.conditions({:person_id => some_id})
```

where `some_id` is an integer value.

**Edit**

you have association so you can use directly as follows:

```
@kases= @person.kases
```

in your `show.rhtml` you can use instance variable directly in your .rhtml
also `@kases` is an array so you have to iterate over it.

```
   <% if @kases.blank?  %>
    No Kase found.
   <% else %>
     <% for kase in @kases %>
       <%=h kase.jobref %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: an integer within which table, the kases one?

Comment: If I use @kases=@person.kases, how do I output the list within the Person show view? Something like this? <% if @person.kases.empty? %>
  No Cases Found
<% end %>

<% if @person.kases %>
<%=h @kase.jobref %>
<% end %>

Comment: You're a bloomin Genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your person model has the association has_many :kases then, you can get all the cases that belongs to a person using this

```
@kases = Person.find(person_id).kases
```

Assuming person_id has the id of the person that you want to see the cases for.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want something like

```
has_many :kases
```

in your Person model, which lets you do `@kases = Person.find(person_id).kases`

as well as everything else that has_many enables.

An alternate method would be to go through Kase directly:

`@kases = Kase.find_all_by_person_id(person_id)`